# Best practice for splitting viewport with CSS flex

Tags: css, flexbox, viewport

Hoping this is not a nonsense question as it is in a way a tad non-specific.

It's quite simple - I am aiming to produce a design splitting the viewport/screen into rough halves (60/40) vertically, similar to how AirBnB do: -

[AirBnB New York](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/newyork?s_tag=n8pN5ljr&allow_override%5B%5D=)

Is this just as simple as using flexbox columns (I am using Bootstrap 4), specifying the column widths and setting the right-hand side column to position: fixed?

Any advice that anyone has would be most welcome as I have never approached this type of design before and I want to make sure I am not overlooking anything.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I accept I did not have my own attempt at code to offer but that was because I simply do not know how to approach viewport splitting at all. I have researched flex and offered my knowledge of it to give a scenario of how it would be approached. I certainly do not want other people writing my code for me as I am not a liberty taker nor would I learn anything from copying and pasting. I was hoping for input to direct me to a solution I could code myself. But I understand your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `flex` layout based solution.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 60vh;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      (60%)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <p>
      <b>content</b>
      (40%)
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```